# How do I access(open/read/etc) /dev devices from a kernel module?

Tags: linux-kernel, device, kernel-module, can-bus, rtai

I have received a driver (PCAN driver for PCI card, using rtdm), that creates /dev/pcan0 and /dev/pcan1 is compiled as a netdev driver.

There are many facilities that come with this driver, but they are all targeted at a user-level program reading CAN messages. What I need however is to read these messages from a kernel module. The PCAN driver doesn't export any variables/functions which means it doesn't provide a kernel-level API for me to use.

I looked briefly at the code and reading from the /dev device and writing to it don't use `copy_from_user` or `copy_to_user`. Therefore, I thought it should be safe for me to open the /dev/pcan0 from my kernel module and read from it.

Now my question is, how do I open/read from a /dev device from a kernel module?

P.S. I want to read from the CAN bus from an RTAI real-time thread, do you think that would cause a problem (for example every read passing through linux kernel and thus breaking real-time conditions?)

Comment: Potentially useful: http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/8110?page=0,0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that I was using RTDM, there were two options:

- Using RTDM direct functions, such rt_dev_open, rt_dev_read etc

  - This is not implemented in the current version of pcan driver
- Using RTDM ioctl

  - This was the solution and it worked

Answer (score 3):

You can use syscalls directly from kernel space: sys_open(), sys_read(), sys_close().
There's [Linuxjournal article](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/8110?page=0,1) about that.

P/S: copy_from_user() works perfectly with kernel-space addresses.

Comment: Thanks for the `copy_from_user` tip.

Comment: I knew that opening a file in kernel space is not a good idea, but I didn't think doing so with /dev/ devices was as bad

Comment: I mean, after all, /dev open/read/write operations basically boil down to a function call to the driver. But thanks, I will try to come up with a different solution

Comment: @Shahbaz r/w any files from kernel space isn't a good idea, but some people do that if they have no choice. Typically, if I have an access to the source code of the module I try to provide API functions for in-kernel operations as well as r/w handlers for user-space.

Comment: Alright thanks. I found out that I in fact could compiler the driver with RTAI and use (not tested yet) rtdm (real-time driver model) to access the driver from kernel space. So, no files anymore.